# Google Static Map

Tags: google-maps

I need to use Google Static Map api, but I need to give it from (latitude, longitude) to (latitude, longitude) and show maps between those two places

can anyone support in this part please

I'm using this code this get map of one place

http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=30.0566,31.2262&format=png32&zoom=10&size=360x602

but I want to get the map between two places

from : 30.0566,31.2262
to : 25.6969,32.6422

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show your current code?, What have you tried?

Comment: this is the url that I'm generated
http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=30.0566,31.2262&format=png32&zoom=10&size=360x602

Comment: Google static maps API is one of the simplest API I have ever seen. Did you read the documentation?

Comment: I'm reading it, but I want to specify from and to places , I can't fine this part in the documentation I found Markers and Paths and many things, so could you please guide me through it ?

Comment: The API does not support such a method of getting the map. What you can do is find the co-ordinates of the center and query for map with appropriate zoom level so that the entire area is covered. Selecting an appropriate zoom level is the main problem here and solution is shown here http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.in/2008/05/app-engine-local-search-maps-making.html

Comment: I have find this way to get place and force some point to appear 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=30.0566,31.2262&visible=25.6969,32.6422&size=360x602

Comment: but the problem now that I need to show the driving direction to draw the path between source and destination place, can you advice me with any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Google Static Maps does not support driving directions.** However it does support drawing lines, including encoded polylines. Everything is subject to the maximum length of a URL (2048 characters).

This means you can use the Directions API server-side, extract the encoded polyline from the results and construct the Static Maps URL using the line.

[Documentation for the Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)